# Can I verify whether the file is present at location in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Currently I have a shell script which takes parameter as file name.

Something like,

```
./myshellscript -inpufile=/data/username/Inputfile.xml
```

I am trying to get the filename using `cut`
and then checking with `-f` but that doesn't work when the

```
-inputfile=~/user/inputfile.xml
```

I need to verify whether the inputfile is present at location `/data/username/`
or location which contains `~`.
It doesn't take the absolute value.

Comment: Is `-inputfile=~/user/inputfile.xml` a valid argument to your script? Are you expecting to take paths with slashes at all or just bare filenames?

Comment: I have shellscript which take numbers of such parameters, to make it order independent. I have appended each parameter with name like.-inpufile=/data/user/myfile.xml . So i have to take -inputfile out and just take /data/user/myfile.xml and check if it exists. In this case ~/bin/myfile.xml does not work

Comment: Right because the placement of `~` in the middle of the string prevented the shell from expanding it. You are going to have a hard time expanding that later (without `eval` which you **should not** use) I believe. Expecting `~` to work there is, sort of, a mistake to begin with. `~` is really only special to the shell and in that context the shell doesn't treat is as special.

Comment: Is there any way I could grep the second part and convert that into shell defined variable?

Comment: The only way I know of to get the shell to expand `~` for you given the way this is working is to use `eval` after you split the value and that's just not, in any way, a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=`basename /data/username/Inputfile.xml`

if [ -e /data/username/$FILE ];
then
   echo "File $FILE exists."
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: Almost there, the above script doesn't convert a `~/whatever` into an absolute path. I've added my attempt below.

Comment: Here,  $1 =  -inpufile=/data/username/Inputfile.xml so i have to first cat the part /data/username/Inputfile.xml using '=' but and then do basename and dirname on that part. But in this case, if we have something like ~/user/myfile/Inputfile.xml then [ -e filename] doesnt work.

Comment: Weird, on my `bash` the test `-e` works fine with a `~/file` argument; e.g., `test -e ~/.bashrc && echo 'found'` prints: `found`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
file=$1

# Normalize the file
absdir=$(dirname $file)
fname=$(basename $file)
absname="$absdir/$fname"

echo "Absolute file name: $absname"

if [ -f $absname ] ; then
    echo "$absname exists"
else
    echo "$absname NOT FOUND"
fi
```

Sample output:

```
$ script.sh /tmp/postgres.log 
Absolute file name: /tmp/postgres.log
/tmp/postgres.log exists

$ script.sh ~/../../tmp/postgres.log 
Absolute file name: /Users/karel/../../tmp/postgres.log
/Users/karel/../../tmp/postgres.log exists
```

So it does normalize `~` but doesn't normalize `../`. Hope this helps..

Comment: Here, $1 = -inpufile=/data/username/Inputfile.xml

Comment: Uh well obviously you need to take off the `-inputfile=`.. The above example is not about how to get at the parameters of your script, but shows how to normalize filenames. Use `cut` or `awk` go get the filename from the argument. Assuming that you already tried something of your own, you must've solved this already (which of course you have, you wouldn't come here asking others to do your coding work.)

Comment: I took of the '-inputfile=' using cut but at the end I am left with '/data/user/inpufile.xml' which can not be used with -f. Because of the single quotes. i want /data/user/inpufile.xml

Comment: Where do your quotes come from? If you'd have as argument: `--inputfile=/data/user/inputfile.xml` and you strip off `--inputfile=` then there are no quotes anywhere..